# C# ¿Como recibir información de un POS?

Tags: c#

estoy desarrollando un Point of Sale (POS) para un local de ropa que tengo, todo bien, ahora lo que quiero hacer es poder integrar el "POSNet" o "laPOS" a mi software. 
He visto en supermercados por ejemplo que pasan la tarjeta por el POSNet o laPOS y siguen el proceso de cobro mediante el Software. Por ejemplo hay un software llamado Tango que tiene esa integración.
Yo tengo un laPOS que tiene para conexion ethernet, Pero no se como recibir la información de alguna forma, alguien podria ayudarme?

Comment: Te contactaste con la gente de laPOS? Ellos deberían darte acceso a alguna librería que te de la posibilidad de usar las funciones del posnet

Comment: Deberias buscar en el sitio de laPOS si disponen de librerias que puedas usar para desarrollar he interacturar, contacta al soporte para consultarles que posibilidades brinda el device